# Perfect Scrollbar : suppressScrollX : true not working in rtl mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, perfect-scrollbar

I am working on a project and there I have used perfect scrollbar all works fine until I have converted my project to support **rtl** mode.

The Scrollbar works perfectly when used with or without `suppressScrollX : true` in **ltr** mode but when comes to **rtl** mode it works perfectly without `suppressScrollX :true` when once I set this parameter it shift my content to the left.

When I inspected I saw that the scroll is automatically increasing the number from left.

Note : I am using `suppressScrollX :true` to remove horizontal scrollbar

Here is my example code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="perfect-scrollbar.css">
    <style>
        html {
            direction: rtl
        }

  #container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="container">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2098427/pexels-photo-2098427.jpeg">
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const ps = new PerfectScrollbar('#container', {
    suppressScrollX : true
  });    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Download working example

https://github.com/Yusufzai/issue-PerfectScrollbarRtl.git